# React Parallel Api calling while Mapping Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the given code, there is a table with user items, and each item has a property called `productHandle`.  By each `productHandle` I want to make api request which will gimme a `productTitle` and `productImage` I need to display this information in a new column in the table. How can I do this efficiently without causing long load times? Should I use `new Promise()` or the `promise.all` method? any example?

Here each user have a `productHandle`. I want to make API request for each item with that `productHandle` which will return `productTitle` and an image and I will display it on table new column.

```
<table className="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>User Id</th>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>Fax</th>
          <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {users.map((user: any, index: number) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{user.userId}</td>
            <td>{user.firstname}</td>
            <td>{user.lastname}</td>
            <td>{user.email}</td>
            <td>{user.phone}</td>
            <td>{user.fax}</td>
            <td>{user.address}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

try code below

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    
    const UserTable = () => {
      const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch user data
        const fetchUsers = async () => {
          try {
            const response = await fetch("API_ENDPOINT"); // Replace with your API endpoint
            const data = await response.json();
            setUsers(data);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching users:", error);
          }
        };
    
        fetchUsers();
      }, []);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch product information for each user
        const fetchProductInfo = async () => {
          const productHandles = users.map((user) => user.productHandle);
          const requests = productHandles.map((handle) =>
            fetch(`PRODUCT_API_ENDPOINT/${handle}`)
          ); // Replace PRODUCT_API_ENDPOINT with your product API endpoint
    
          try {
            const responses = await Promise.all(requests);
            const productData = await Promise.all(responses.map((res) => res.json()));
    
            // Update user data with product information
            const updatedUsers = users.map((user, index) => ({
              ...user,
              productTitle: productData[index].productTitle,
              productImage: productData[index].productImage,
            }));
    
            setUsers(updatedUsers);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching product information:", error);
          }
        };
    
        if (users.length > 0) {
          fetchProductInfo();
        }
      }, [users]);
    
      return (
        <table className="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>User Id</th>
              <th>Firstname</th>
              <th>Lastname</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Phone</th>
              <th>Fax</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Product Title</th>
              <th>Product Image</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {users.map((user: any, index: number) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>{user.userId}</td>
                <td>{user.firstname}</td>
                <td>{user.lastname}</td>
                <td>{user.email}</td>
                <td>{user.phone}</td>
                <td>{user.fax}</td>
                <td>{user.address}</td>
                <td>{user.productTitle}</td>
                <td>
                  <img src={user.productImage} alt="Product" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      );
    };
    
    export default UserTable;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You've posted 9 answers so far over the last 24 hours, and most of them are either mostly code with no explanation, appear likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT), or both. A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. For answers where you have not used AI, keep in mind that providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* your code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.